# Load comment data from json file using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I got stuck when I want to load a comment data to a section tag using jquery ajax.

There is nothing displayed on my website.

Here is my html:

```
<section id="comments">
<header>
   <h2>Comments</h2>
</header>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script>
   $.ajax({
      url :"comments.json",
      type : "GET",
      dataType : "json",
      data : {get_param : 'value'},
      success : function(data){
         // Hitung jumlah data
         jData = data.length;

         // Buat variable untuk section komentar
         secKomen = "";

         // Looping section komentar
         for(a = 0; a < jData; a++){                  
            // Membuat section komentar baru
            secKomen += "<section>"

            // menampilkan foto
            //+ '<figure>' + '<img src="data[a]['avatar']"/>'

            // membuat artikel
            + "<article>"
            // membuat tag header
            + "<header>" + "<cite>" + data[a]["name"] + "</cite>" + "<time>" + data[a]["data"] + "</time>" + "</header>"
            // isi komentar
            + data[a]["comment"]
            + "</article>"
            // section close
            + "</section>";
         }
         // mencetak tabel
         document.getElementById("comments")[0].innerHTML += secKomen;
      }
   });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url :"comments.json",
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            data : {get_param : 'value'},
            success : function(data){
                // Hitung jumlah data
                jData = data.length;

                // Buat variable untuk section komentar
                secKomen = "";

                // Looping section komentar
                for(a = 0; a < jData; a++){

                    // Membuat section komentar baru
                    secKomen += "<section>"

                                // menampilkan foto
                                //+ '<figure>' + '<img src="data[a]['avatar']"/>'

                                // membuat artikel
                                + "<article>"
                                // membuat tag header
                                + "<header>" + "<cite>" + data[a]["name"] + "</cite>" + "<time>" + data[a]["data"] + "</time>" + "</header>"
                                // isi komentar
                                + data[a]["comment"]
                                + "</article>"
                            // section close
                            + "</section>";
                }
                // mencetak tabel
                //document.getElementById("comments")[0].innerHTML += secKomen;
                jQuery('#comments').html(secKomen);
            }
        });
    </script>
```